Signature verification information in Adobe Reader
In Adobe Reader (and Foxit PDF Reader) there is a possibility to make non-LTV signature (without trusted timestamp), a LTV signature by adding verification information. Something is then added to the PDF file. Questions:

How exactly does it work? What is added to the file? How/why is it trusted by other software (at least Foxit<->Adobe)?
Can I produce such LTV signature (without trusted timestamp) in my own signing software?

